# RadListView and Observable Items - application crash on setting items value

Tags: arrays, observable, nativescript, radlistview

I have a Vanilla Nativescript app that I am testing a RadListView on; populating the items from JS.

As soon as I SET the value of the ObservableArray the app just crashes. I have tried to set the value onload as well as on tap. In this example tab on the BOTTOM LABEL; at the moment a label at the top will display the set value so I know that the object does exist; but when trying to bind the data to the list view things go awry.

Below is the base code to replicate this issue; if you uncomment the line:

**pageData.set("items", items);**

Any direction would be much appreciated.

**HOME-PAGE.XML**

```
<Page class="page"
    navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"  
    loaded="pageLoaded" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
    xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview"
>

    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
        <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Home"></Label>
    </ActionBar>

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Add your page content here -->

        <Label  text="{{ toptext }}" textAlignment="center" color="#88f" fontSize="15" fontWeight="bold"/>


        <lv:RadListView height="350" items="{{ items }}" >
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ itemName }}"/>
                <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ itemDescription }}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    </lv:RadListView>

        <Label  text="BOTTOM LABEL" textAlignment="center" color="#f88" fontSize="33" fontWeight="bold" onTap="fillListview"/>

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**HOME-PAGE.JS**

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

var items = new ObservableArray();

var pageData = new Observable();



function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();

}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;


exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;

    items.push(
        {
            itemName: "$USD / ZAR",
            itemDescription: "13.50",
            itemDate: "3 Jul 2019",
            itemImage: "~/images/arcade-fire.png"
        },
        {
            itemName: "$USD / ZAR",
            itemDescription: "18.00",
            itemDate: "17 Aug 2019",
            itemImage: "~/images/bon-iver.png"
        }
    )



};




exports.fillListview = function(args) {

    pageData.set("toptext", items);
//  pageData.set("items", items);

}
```

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to reproduce your problem in a playground project but all works fine, do you recive some error in console about your problem ??

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=MCM9ut&v=6) is the project where i was trying your code

Comment: thanks for the response .. this playground is the same as mine .. however i am experiencing the same behaviour .. to clarify:

1. when i TAP on the "BOTTOM LABEL" text in the simulator the APP just crashes, if I comment out the line below the app does not crash:
pageData.set("items", items);

2. In the playground there seems to be a UI updating issue? .. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here but the observable fields dont appear to update on the UI unless I resave the XML file and the app 'refreshes' the page?

Comment: CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/trace/trace.js:174:22: Binding: Property: 'itemName' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'itemName'
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/trace/trace.js:174:22: Binding: Property: 'itemDescription' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'itemDescription'

Comment: this is very strange , if you dont mind zip your project to check it,maybe the playground project have some diference with your demo... also check if you are using the lastes version of ns

Comment: What a wild goose chase - my apologies MCorzo and ManoJ .. Updating and upgrading the modules seems to have done the trick! I do appreciate you taking the time to have a look see.